# std::string_view issues on GCC8

Tags: c++17, gcc-warning, string-view

I have some simple code using `std::string_view` which works great in gcc10, but not in gcc8.

`std::string_view` was added to [C++17 in GCC 7](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/17#C.2B.2B17_library_features), so it should be possible to use this.

```
#include <string_view>
using sv = std::string_view;

sv ParseScheme(const sv& url)
{
    sv pattern = "://";
    if (auto found = url.find(pattern); found != sv::npos)
    {
        return sv(url.begin(), url.begin() + found);
    }
    return sv();
}
```

Compiling gives me:

```
$ g++ main.cpp --std=c++17 -Werror
main.cpp: In function 'sv ParseScheme(const sv&)':
main.cpp:9:44: error: invalid conversion from
    'std::basic_string_view<char>::const_iterator' {aka 'const char*'} to 
    'std::basic_string_view<char>::size_type' {aka 'long unsigned int'} [-fpermissive]
         return sv(url.begin(), url.begin() + found);
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/string_view:105:56: note:   initializing argument 2 of 
    'constexpr std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_string_view(
        const _CharT*, std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>::size_type
    ) [with 
        _CharT = char; 
        _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; 
        std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>::size_type = long unsigned int
    ]'
       basic_string_view(const _CharT* __str, size_type __len) noexcept
                                              ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

Is there something I'm actually doing wrong, or are `string_view`s in gcc8 just broken?

I could use `-fpermissive` to ignore the issue, but we compile with `-Werror`, so an `-fpermissive` warning will fail the build anyways.

Comment: The constructor you are using was added in C++20 (see #5 in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view)

Comment: `return sv(url.data(), found);` should work in C++17

Comment: Yes, it does.  Thanks.  But what if I want the second-half of the string_view?  `return sv(url.begin() + found, url.end())` will run into the same problem

Comment: I guess the "solution" would be to use `sv.substr` in that case

Comment: Ah, it would be `sv(url.data() + found, url.size() - found)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `string_view(Iterator,Iterator)` [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view) used here was added in C++20.  that's why it doesn't work in [gcc8](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx20).

An alternative is to use the `string_view(const char*, size_type)` constructor availalbe in C++17:

```
#include <string_view>
using sv = std::string_view;

sv ParseScheme(const sv& url)
{
    sv pattern = "://";
    if (auto found = url.find(pattern); found != sv::npos)
    {
        return sv(url.data() + found, url.size() - found);
    }
    return sv();
}
```